# The method in the sub Class does not show up in main game Class

Tags: c#, monogame

my game class is this

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;

namespace testReadXmlGame
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This is the main type for your game.
    /// </summary>
    public class Game1 : Game
    {
        GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;

        static List<List<string>> imageData = new List<List<string>>();

        public Game1()
        {
            graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
        }

        protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed || Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
                Exit();



            base.Update(gameTime);
        }
        protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

            // TODO: Add your drawing code here

            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }

        #region Public methods

        #endregion
    }
}
```

and my class to get data from an xml file into a list is this.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml;

namespace testReadXmlGame
{
    public class XmlFileRead
    {
        #region Fields

        private bool addToFile = false;
        List<List<string>> imageData = new List<List<string>>();

        #endregion

        #region Public methods

        public List<List<string>> XmlDataToList(string pathToXmlFile)
        {
            XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(pathToXmlFile);
            while (xmlReader.Read())
            {
                List<string> tempData = new List<string>(); // create a temp list to add data from each node

                while (xmlReader.MoveToNextAttribute())
                {
                    tempData.Add(xmlReader.Value);
                    addToFile = true;
                }

                if (addToFile)
                {
                    imageData.Add(tempData);
                    addToFile = false;
                }
            }
            // below code used to check the contents of the list returned
            for (int i = 1; i <= imageData.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < imageData[i].Count; j++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(imageData[i][j]);
                }
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
            return imageData;
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

I want to add

```
imageData = XmlReadFile.XmlDataToList(string nameOfXmlFile)
```

in the update field.

What I am trying to do is call the XmlFileRead method from the Game class while passing it the location of the xml file and then read the xml file and return a list back to the Main Game class.

My problem is the method is not even showing up in the Main Game class. Can someone please help to solve the problem. Please don't only point out the errors but help me with a solution as I am new to C# and Monogame.

Comment: What do you mean by “not showing up”? What did you try to write?

Comment: XmlFileRead is a class not a method, unless you mean its constructor?

Comment: I edited the question and showed exactly what i want to do.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with the code below.

```
namespace testReadXmlGame
{
    public static class XmlFileRead
    {
        #region public methods

        public static List<List<string>> XmlDataToList(string pathToXmlFile, bool addToFile, List<List<string>> imageData)
        {
            XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(pathToXmlFile);
            while (xmlReader.Read())
            {
                List<string> tempData = new List<string>(); // create a temp list to add data from each node

                while (xmlReader.MoveToNextAttribute())
                {
                    tempData.Add(xmlReader.Value);
                    addToFile = true;
                }

                if (addToFile)
                {
                    imageData.Add(tempData);
                    addToFile = false;
                }
            }

            return imageData;
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

declaring the following in the main game class

```
static List<List<string>> imageData = new List<List<string>>();
bool addToFile = false;
```

and then calling `XmlFileRead.XmlDataToList` from the main class with

```
imageData = XmlFileRead.XmlDataToList("alienExplode.xml", addToFile, imageData);
```